# SQL Server - Counting dates per item and arranging in groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions

I have a query that outputs an ID and a Date, such as:

```
[ID]      [DateValue]
A111111   2015-01-01
A111111   2015-01-02
A111111   2015-01-03
A111111   2015-01-04
A222222   2015-01-01
A222222   2015-01-02
A333333   2015-01-01
A333333   2015-01-02
A333333   2015-01-03
```

From this resultset, I need to determine one, two, and greater than two date groups that groups the count of each ID. For instance, the output needs to be something like the following for the data above:

```
[OneDay]  [TwoDays]  [MoreThanTwoDays]
 3         3          2
```

Would I have to pivot this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it count number of unique days, or the distance between min and max dates? Or rather, which one would you prefer if there where gaps?

Comment: @Markus It counts the number of unique days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #test
    (
      id VARCHAR(100) ,
      [DateValue] DATE
    );
INSERT  INTO #test
VALUES
        ( 'A111111', '2015-01-01' ),
        ( 'A111111', '2015-01-02' ),
        ( 'A111111', '2015-01-03' ),
        ( 'A111111', '2015-01-04' ),
        ( 'A222222', '2015-01-01' ),
        ( 'A222222', '2015-01-02' ),
        ( 'A333333', '2015-01-01' ),
        ( 'A333333', '2015-01-02' ),
        ( 'A333333', '2015-01-03' );

SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN qty = 1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END) AS [OneDay] ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN qty = 2 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END) AS [TwoDays] ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN qty > 2 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END) AS [MoreThanTwoDays]
FROM
    (
      SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS qty
      FROM
        #test
      GROUP BY
        [DateValue]
    ) a;
```